# Canon DSLR T5 Lens Compatibility

Tags: lens, canon

Can anyone tell me if my Canon EF lenses can be used on a Canon Rebel t5(1200D)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I [looked it up](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_rebel_t5_18_55_is_ii_kit#BoxContenthttp://) to be sure.  To be clear, EF lenses fit on a camera that uses EF-S. EF-S sticks farther into the camera. [Look for the white alignment mark](http://photonotes.org/articles/beginner-faq/lenses.html) to tell if they will physically mount on your camera.

Comment: This  answer is misleading. Sure the EF mount is older than the EF-S, but that doesn't mean that the DSLR:s with large mirrors are older. Large mirrors are a fact among full frame cameras and there are new models with them (the most recent being the 6D). There will most likely be a lot more FF cameras exclusive to the EF mount in the future too.

Comment: I recall reading that newer models of full-frame cameras were fesigned to accept the deeper element. Now I can't find it but did see *"All consumer to midrange digital EOS cameras released since [2003] have been both EF and EF-S compatible."*

Comment: @jdlugosz: that's because there are no full-frame consumer to midrange digital EOS cameras.

Comment: @jdlugosz - just to confirm, new full frame canon DSLRs are not compatible with EF-s.  Certain EF-s lenses could break my 5D Mark iii if I forced them on it and the warnings still appear in the manuals for current model FF Canon cameras (in addition to the mount not physically fitting them).